# Concating first name, last name fields so it can befit in case statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, concatenation

I have to recreate a stored procedure which existed in `DB1`, and map the existing tables to new tables in the new database `DB2`.

In `DB1`, table there was column `Fullname` and in the new db there are two columns `firstname`, `lastname`. I could have concat but there is a user defined function also which truncates all special characters which I have to use.

How do I use the first name and last name columns as one full name column so that it fits this case statement?

I am getting the [P Name] from another table enrolled enr which is like the master table having all the names, getting names from either tables is conditioned as shown in case statement.

I tried searching all blogs and stackexchange but cannot get the desired reply.

```
masterfinancer = dbo.fn_RemoveSpecialChars(iif(enr.p_name = 'XXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXX(2)', 'XXXXX XXXX XXX GROUP', mv.master_vendor_name))
Sma_finace_key = iif(enr.p_name = 'XXXXXXXXX0L(2)', 1111, mv.ven_key)

[P Name]  = case 
               when enr.p_name = 'INACTIVE ' or enr.p_name = 'UNASSIGNED'
                  then [P Name] 
                  else dbo.fn_RemoveSpecialChars(enr.p_name) 
            end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the function on each separate field and join them together. Here I removed the IIF statements (which only work in SQL 2012) and created a FullName field that assumes you want "First, Last". I added COALESCE to avoid the FullName field being NULL when either the first or last names are NULL:

```
SELECT
    masterfinancer = dbo.fn_RemoveSpecialChars(
            CASE 
                WHEN enr.p_name = 'XXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXX(2)' 
                THEN 'XXXXX XXXX XXX GROUP' 
                ELSE mv.master_vendor_name 
            END)
    , Sma_finace_key = 
            CASE 
                WHEN enr.p_name = 'XXXXXXXXX0L(2)' 
                THEN 1111 
                ELSE mv.ven_key 
            END
    , [P Name]  = 
            CASE 
                WHEN enr.p_name IN('INACTIVE ', 'UNASSIGNED')
                THEN [P Name] 
                ELSE dbo.fn_RemoveSpecialChars(enr.p_name) 
            END
, FullName = 
    COALESCE(dbo.fn_RemoveSpecialChars(enr.last_name) + ', ', '') + 
    COALESCE(dbo.fn_RemoveSpecialChars(enr.first_name), '')
```